# What is the computational complexity limitation of classical client delegated quantum computing CCDQC protocols?

Tags: cryptography, blind-quantum-computing

The number of T-gates in quantum search reaches $O(2^{m/2} \cdot\text{poly}(m))$, which is beyond the capability of CHE-based QHE schemes.

But is it the same case for other bilnd QC protocols?  and What is the computational complexity limitation of the remote state preparation protocols that enable a fully classical client to delegate a computation to an untrusted quantum server securely?